# Z-Index - Child won't go below parent

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having an issue with Z-index.

I'm building a dropdown menu, when you hover over the list item it shows the sub dropdown.

I want it to start off the screen around -400px then dropdown but I don't want it to be above the red header when it's dropping down and sliding back up.

How can I get the sub dropdown below the red header so it's only showing directly below the list item on the grey body background?

Thanks

```css
html,
body,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  background: red;
}

.list-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.list-item:hover .sub-dropdown {
  /*top: 100%;*/
  /*visibility: visible;
                opacity: 1;*/
}

.sub-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  /*visibility: hidden;
                opacity: 0;*/
  /*transition: 0.25s;*/
  z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-dropdown">
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufgqsw95/1/

Comment: Add matched background colour to dropdown class then try.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? I removed the z-index.

```css
html,
body,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

header {
  background: red;
}

.list-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.list-item:hover .sub-dropdown {
  animation: showsub 0.5s forwards;
}

.sub-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: -400px;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes showsub {
  0% {
    top: -400px; z-index: -1;
  }
  50% {
    top: 0; z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%; z-index: 0;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-dropdown">
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: This still overlays the red background on transition.

Comment: Code and animation adjusted

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I'm setting it to -400px is to achieve a slidedown effect. This is just fading in currently because at 0% you're already at top:100% rather than sliding down which is why I need the red background to cover so it's hidden until it's below that bar.

Comment: Got it. Hidden now and sliding in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, no need of Z-index.

```
.list-item:hover .sub-dropdown {top: 100%;display:block;}
.sub-dropdown {position: absolute;display:none;}
```

Comment: No because if you use display: none/display: block you can't transition it so it slides down without using JQuery.

Answer (score -1):

The sub-dropdown needs a z-index of -1 and the list-item needs a z-index of 1.

```
.list-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sub-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Then, on :hover you can give the sub-dropdown top: 100%.

```
.list-item:hover .sub-dropdown {
    top: 100%;
}
```

Is that the desired outcome: https://jsfiddle.net/ufgqsw95/2/ ?